# Multiple plotLines using options in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts to build three charts on the same page and would like to show multiple plotLines on them. My current code only renders the last plotLine value (or first value if i remove the brackets). example:

```
options.xAxis.plotLines[0] = ({value: 17.53, color: '#444', width: 1, dashStyle: 'solid'}, {value: 29.52, color: '#444', width: 1, dashStyle: 'solid'});
```

Any help would be great.

Full code (with data removed)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 

 Highcharts.setOptions({
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: null
            }

        });

var options = {

    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Route'
    },

    plotOptions: {

        areaspline:
            {
            lineColor: null,
            fillColor: 'green',
            lineWidth:0,
            marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
            }




    },
    credits: { enabled: false },
    yAxis: {

        min: 0,
        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        gridLineColor:null,
        lineColor:'#333',

        title:{text:null},
        labels:{enabled:true},
        legend:{enabled:false },
        title: {
                text: null
                }
    },

       xAxis: {

        plotLines: []

         },


        series: [{
            showInLegend: false
                },

]
};

        options.chart.renderTo = ‘Chart1’;
        options.title.text = 'Chart1';
        options.series[0].data = [[0.05,75]… // Data ];
        options.plotOptions.areaspline.fillColor = '#0066CC';
        options.xAxis.plotLines[0] = ({value: 15.44, color: '#444', width: 1, dashStyle: 'solid'}, {value: 18.23, color: '#444', width: 1, dashStyle: 'solid'});
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        options.chart.renderTo = 'Chart2’;
        options.title.text = 'Chart2’;
        options.series[0].data = [[0.05,75]… // Data ];
        options.plotOptions.areaspline.fillColor = '#FF0033';
        options.xAxis.plotLines[0] = ({value: 17.53, color: '#444', width: 1, dashStyle: 'solid'}, {value: 29.52, color: '#444', width: 1, dashStyle: 'solid'});
        var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        options.chart.renderTo = 'Chart3’;
        options.title.text = 'Chart3’;
        options.series[0].data = [[0.05,79]… // Data ];
        options.plotOptions.areaspline.fillColor = '#48BC26';

        var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);






})

</script>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="Chart1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 140px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="Chart2” style="min-width: 310px; height: 140px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="Chart3” style="min-width: 310px; height: 140px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. The plotLines values needed to be pushed:

```
options.xAxis.plotLines.push
```